# Can I check the condition and change the value of variable in ng-click

Tags: angularjs

```
ng-click="(document.getElementById('procheck1').checked)?showme=true:showme=false"
```

(or)

```
ng-click="if(document.getElementById('procheck1').checked){showme=true;}else{showme=false;}"
```

Comment: If any one know the correct statement , comment below

Comment: so you need it to be right there in `ng-click="here"`? why not do it using a function?

Comment: I have already tried this using function ....but that's not working because angularjs ng-show variable's value cannot be changed in function

Comment: we should try a solution inline

Comment: ng-show variable's value can be changed in function if you have it defined in the `$scope`.

Comment: can u give the answer with exact syntax

Comment: sure, just post the HTML and JS related to the question

Comment: <div ng-hide="showme==true"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="allstock">Col<br>
<ul id="myUL" ng-repeat="user in stockList">
<li><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allstock" ng-click="stocktest=true" id="procheck1">{{user.Stockarea}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div ng-show="showme==true">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allproduct">Min<br>
<ul id="myUL" ng-repeat="user in productList">
<li><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allproduct" id="procheck2">{{user.Product}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<button ng-click="(document.getElementById('procheck1').checked)?showme=true:showme=false">Click</button>

Answer (score 0):

Use some function name like this , ng-click="myFunction()"  and write whole condition inside that.

```
  myFunction(){
    if(document.getElementById('procheck1').checked) {
      showme=true;
    } else {
      showme=false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have already tried this one ....but thats not working because angularjs ng-show variable's value cannot be changed in function

Comment: we should try to change this in inline

Comment: with showme=true, you might want to show some div element.Right?

Comment: Can you provide me html code and tell me what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in html page

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <label for="chkPassport">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkPassport" ng- model="ShowPassport" ng-change="ShowHide()" />
            Do you have Passport?
        </label>
        <hr />
        <div ng-show="IsVisible">
            Passport Number:
            <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this part in controller

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
  app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
            //This will hide the DIV by default.
            $scope.IsVisible = false;
            $scope.ShowHide = function () {
                //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
                $scope.IsVisible = $scope.ShowPassport;
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry, its not working the div is visible by default and does not change

Comment: Can you post your code here . So I can understand the exact problem

Comment: use ng-model instead of ng-checked

Comment: One more thing  as you doing repetition over stockList and productList, you can't use  same id "procheck1".